# Using Nunjucks in an Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Node app that includes Express. Up to this point, I've been using Swig as my view engine. I configured this view engine like this:

```
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

This approach has worked for me. But, since Swig has been deprecated, I'm trying to move to Nunjucks. In an attempt to do this, I've done the following:

```
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    cache: false,
    express: app        
});

app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

This doesn't work. I get a runtime error, but I can't tell what error is actually thrown. In an attempt to load the most basic view, I'm trying to load the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is intentionally a really basic HTML view that does NOT use any templating. I just want to be able to load an HTML view with nunjucks set as the view engine. Even with this, I still get an error.

I can see that [render function](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html), has a callback. It looks like the callback has an error object I could look at. But, I don't know how to actually use that callback within the line `app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);`.

Any insights would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Updated Code:

```
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var app = express();

// looks for html in views folder relative to current working directory
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    cache: false,
    express: app
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

Comment: When I do that, I get an error that says: `[Error: template not found: index.html]`. Where is nunjucks expecting index.html to be? I would assume it's looking for ./views/index.html. But apparently, it's not.

Comment: Got it. I replaced 'views' with `path.join(__dirname, '../views')`. Now, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed the following configuration for Express 4.15.3 with Nunjucks 3.0.1.

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    cache: false,
    express: app
});
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```